# How to fetch data from URL

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, url

I have a URL http://localhost/TradeCredits/UnderWriter/EditQuote.aspx?QOT_ID=1 I want to fetch QOT_ID from URL . Please suggest how to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this line of code:

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["QOT_ID"]);
```

Or this if you want to do proper checking:

```
int id;
if (int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["QOT_ID"], out id)) {
    // Do something with the id variable
} else {
    // Do something when QOT_ID cannot be parsed into an int
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have an `URL` as you mentioned in your question which may not be connected to the current request you could do it like this:

```
string url = "http://localhost/TradeCredits/UnderWriter/EditQuote.aspx?QOT_ID=1";
Uri uri = new Uri(url);
var parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
var id = parameters["QOT_ID"];
```

and `id` variable holds your parameter's value.

Comment: I believe you meant `Uri uri = new Uri(url);`?

Answer (score 0):

The [`Request.QueryString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784.aspx) collection contains all the URL parameters - each can be accessed by name:

```
var val = Request.QueryString["QOT_ID"];
```

All returned values are `string` variables, so you may need to cast to the appropriate type.

Answer (score 0):

Request.QueryString gives you array of string variables sent to the client

```
Request.QueryString["QOT_ID"]
```

See [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

QOT_ID could be null or a combination of letters

```
int id = Request.QueryString["QOT_ID"] != null && Int32.TryParse(Request.QueryString["QOT_ID"]) ? int.Parse(Request.QueryString["QOT_ID"]) : -1;
```

Not 100% sure if you can safely pass a null value to Int32.TryParse.

Comment: `Request.QueryString[]` is guaranteed not to return `null`.

Comment: I was surprised by this since i always check for null in my current projects, so i tested this. Request.QueryString does infact return null if the index/name you pass doesn't exist ...